# iOS - Row in UITableView contents getting truncated

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uilabel

I am developing an iOS Application which has an UITableview. There are three items which needs to be displayed in each of the rows in the UITableview.

The data to the table is fetched from the web server as a JSON object. All is working fine and I am happy except 2 issues which I am facing.

ISSUE 1:
The first component in a row is a Label and this label is not displaying the data completely. The label is configured to be multiline (currently with 7 lines). But sometime only one word comes into this label. In that case there is a lot of blank space between the label which is component 1 and component 2 which is again an label. If I configure this label to be single line and if the length of the label content is more, then this row gets displayed as below

a quick brown fox jumps over…

The sentence gets truncated and ends with three dots. Any idea how to adjust the height of this label dynamically based on the length of the contents in the label without changing the font size and as a result the row size [wrt table] also gets changed .

ISSUE 2: This is with respect to the third component in the row. The issue is similar to issue one but very complex in nature compared to ISSUE1. This also mainly deals with truncation. The template which I designed for this component is like below

SD contact name1 [SD contact number]-->SD contact name2 [SD contact number2]

where SD is Service Desk FYI

In actual not all four details are available.

If service is closed, Only SD contact name1 should appear like below

SD contact name

But I am getting like below in actual

SD.. [     ]-->  [    ]

SD contact name1 is truncated to SD.. and empty brackets appear.

If service is open and is in second level , I need this component to appear as below

SD contact name1 --> SD contact name2[+34434344]. But I am getting like below

SD..[     ]--> SD..[+33..]

Again, empty brackets and truncated data.

How to make the brackets and square invisible. Is there a delegate method available where OI can make them disappear based on some condition.

With respect to truncation, I tried the method **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth**
But the font size gets reduced and I am unable to read the sentence or the phone numbers. 
is there a good way of handling this issue. Thanks for your support.[image]

I have attached the storyboard for your reference. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please override the delegate method

    `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //get values to put in the cell using indexPath.row
 Int totalHeight =0;
 //calculate height of first label add it to totalHeight
//calculate height of second label add it to totalHeight`

return totalHeight;
}

Calculate and return the height the row needs to be

then in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

calculate and set the height and width of each label.

```
NSString *labelText=@"some text";
        [myLabel setText:labelText];
        UIFont *labelTextFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:labelTextsize];
        CGSize labelFrameSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:labelTextFont];
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, labelFrameSize.width, labelFrameSize.height);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Premsuraj. I am able to understand the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate. How about heightForRowAtIndexPath. What goes in heightForRowAtIndexPath? Can you please explain me. Thanks